# React Firebase authentication persistence

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, react-typescript

I have implemented firebase authentication (login and register with email) in my React app, but now I want to upgrade with remember me checkbox. I'm familiar with onAuthStateChanged listener, and partially I know how it works. In last app I used Context(onAuthStaeChanged was in Context), but now I'm not using it and I'm trying to figure out where is best place to set that listener.

Also for remember me checkbox I'm trying to find some documentation on firebase and didn't manage to find anything except setPersistence .. but they didn't really explained it well, atleast not for me :P. I guess that default persistence is local so it should be set when checkbox is checked, and session when checkbox is unchecked.

So if any1 have any expirience with this, my question is where is best place to set useEffect with onAuthStateChanged and how to implement checkbox remember be, because user is always staying logged in by default?

I'm not providing any code since It's really basic code from firebase authentication.I have Login, Register and Home component. But in case someone need to see my code to help me I will edit post with code sample. Thanks!

Comment: With 'remember me', you mean the login form? Where users type in their email / username and password? You want that the browser autofills those inputs and the user just needs to click 'ok'? Is this what you are looking for?

Comment: @wenzf If user check remember me checkbox he should stay logged in untill he manually log out, but if user don't check checkbox he should be logged off when he close tab

Comment: I think in this case, I can't help you. From my experience firebase users stay loged in until logded off - even after reloading the site. Maybe you can try to  return the logout function in a useEffect, so it might log out when the app unmounts. [edited some typos]

Comment: @wenzf Yeah thats what I was thinking, but in that case user will be logged out on every page refresh. Gonna have to brainstorm this problem out haha. Anyway thanks for response mate!

Comment: Ah... you are right. How using localStorage? In case 'not remember me', store an item in localStorage. When the app mounts, it checks localStorage for that item and sets it to state. If the state is true, return the signout function in the useEffect.

Comment: @wenzf Mate that is great idea, since this is just my practice project and not real one. I think this might be solution for my problem. Can you post that as answer so I can check it up as answer?

Comment: I think there might be better solutions provided by firebase api directly, somwhere hidden in the documentation. -  Aside of that I doubt that the signout function would be called. - Closing the browser tab is not the same than when a component is unmounted within the app. But maybe worth a try, never tried it.

Comment: @wenzf I'm gonna try to find something in docs, can't believe that there is not much about this theme lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it in this very simple way:

```
import { browserSessionPersistence, setPersistence } from "firebase/auth";

const handleSubmit = (e: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
e.preventDefault();
if (!authPersistence) {
  setPersistence(auth, browserSessionPersistence);
}
signInWithEmailAndPassword(authForm.email, authForm.password);
};
```

Checkbox html:

```
<label>
  <input
    type="checkbox"
    onClick={(e) => setAuthPersistence(!authPersistence)}
  />
  Remember me
</label>
```

So if user check checkbox state changed to true and setPersistence will not be triggered. BrowserSessionPersistence is that if user close tab or browser he will be logged out, and I think that browsetSessionLocal is default value, but in this case I don't have to deal with it :).
Edit: On refresh or loading another component user is not logged off.